# Using Slice Block in Simulink

Tags: fpga, simulink, xilinx

I am having some trouble using the Slice block(Xilinx Bit Slice Extractor). 
I need to extract 2 bits before the Binary Point of Input.

So if the input is represented in 2's complement, and if the input is say for instance 2.25

It would represented as 000**10**.01000000. So I need to extract only 2 bits before the binary point. (10 in this case)

If not Slice Block, is there any technique which gives me more flexibility in extracting the required bits.

I am having similar problem using Bitbasher block.

Thanks
Kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your slice block parameters as:

- Width of slice = 2
- "lower bit location + width"
- Offset of bottom bit = 0
- relative to: Binary point of input

I'm not sure that you can be that detailed with the BitBasher.